# Traverse a circular path

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry

I have an image that consists of concentric circles. How do I traverse each circle separately (knowing the Center coordinates and radius) in MATLAB?

Comment: What do you really want to do? What do you mean by "traverse" -- iterate along each pixel, and `doSomething()` at each one?

Answer (score 0):

if I think I understand the question correctly you are looking for a circle around a given point on an image. I have posted some code below, that will retrieve these points for you.

```
im = zeros([50,50]);
center = [20,20];
radius = 5;
x = 1:size(im,1);
y = 1:size(im,2);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x-center(1),y-center(2));
dist = sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2)
circle = dist > radius-1 & dist < radius+1;
```

`im` would just be whatever the image is your are looking at

Comment: I meant I have to extract one circle and make all others disappear on the output.

Comment: I used the condition if (pixel)= (x^2+y^2 < r^2) || (x^2+y^2>r^2) make them of value 255, others retain the same . It worked. Thanks .